# PayPal Instant Update API not working on HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, spree

We are building an online store that is based on Spree and hosted on Heroku. We want to make the checkout as easy as possible so we decided to use PayPal Express Checkout, and Instant Update API to determine the shipping cost.

When we tested the checkout process over HTTP, everything works perfectly - when the user enters his shipping address, PayPal queries our server in the background and obtains the shipping costs.

However when we switched to SSL, the shipping cost just doesn't update and reverts to the default flat-rate. I cannot figure out what is wrong because everything is the same, except this time the app is accessed through HTTPS, i.e. https://myapp.herokuapp.com

I have check the logs and I see that PayPal's server did make the query, but the shipping cost just don't update on PayPal's checkout page.

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

**Update:**

After further testing, it seems PayPal is not obeying the timeout set in the transaction setup. We added a simple "sleep(x)" to the callback method to artificially induce some delay (by x seconds), and even over normal HTTP, just 1 second delay is enough to caused PayPal to ignore the response.

The max timeout is supposed to be 6 seconds, but in reality it doesn't seem to be the case at all. And couple that with HTTPS (which take longer to establish a connection), it is probably why the callback was failing in the first place.

I have submitted a ticket to PayPal, but I'm not sure if they will respond or do anything about it...

Comment: did you ever get a response?

Comment: No. For now, we have given up on instant shipping update and let the users choose the shipping :(

Comment: I reported to Paypal and they just wrote me back saying they fixed it yesterday! I can't test it because my BIOS update just trashed my laptop but will test ASAP and report back. Unfortunately that was all they said - no acknowledgement of details on the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are many reasons that PayPal could ignore the returned shipping options from the callback.

I'd like to see something on PayPal's site that would keep a history of recent calls to the callback with the returned response and reasons for rejection - somewhat similar to the useful IPN history.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you posted your real domain name here because you've pretty much confirmed my suspicions.

I'm pretty convinced the problem is that you have a wildcard SSL (I see your certificate is issued to `*.herokuapp.com`) and not just an SSL for a single domain.

I am having the same problem with a UCC certificate for `www.MicroPedi.com` which is a 5 name UCC certificate. PayPal just flat out refuses to even make any calls to it (I have logging and nothing is coming through except when using the sandbox).

---

To confirm this I have a previous Express checkout implementation that is working just fine (with a single SSL) and I pointed my new application to that old URL and it magically started working again. That is a single name SSL - in fact it's one of those expensive `green bar` certificates.

I've written directly to PayPal support, but right now the only thing I can think of doing as a workaround is writing some kind of proxy page that will just redirect from the good domain to my UCC domain.

Comment: I see you actually said your server DID receive the call. I still think that what I found out is true, but I can't take this @*&# any more today so I'll just post back if I find out more

Comment: Wildcard SSL was our first suspect too, and we actually tested a single name certificate as well. We could get it working on our local dev machine, however when we put it on Heroku it just stops working again.

Comment: After more testing we found that it is probably because PayPal does not respect the callback timeout (see the update in my original post). The SSL handshake/connection just takes too long on our production site. Maybe you could try adding some artificial delay to your callback to see if it fails too (like sleeping 1 or 2 seconds).

Comment: In my case it was definitely not accepting my SSL. I ended up having to made a proxy file on the 'good' SSL over to my other site. Whatever checks and balances it's doing it's not letting me know so I have no choice unless PayPal writes me back